# Parsing where clause as string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following where clause as a string in Java. I want to parse out the sub-select statements into two strings.

```
where create_dtm between (
select start_dtm FROM schema.table 
where table_ID = (SELECT MAX(table_ID) 
FROM schema.table WHERE MAINT_APP = 'JOB01')) 
and (
select end_dtm FROM schema.table
where table_ID = (SELECT MAX(table_ID) 
FROM schema.table WHERE MAINT_APP = 'JOB01'))
```

I am having trouble creating a regex pattern to properly get these values since it is a bit tricky to distinguish the end points of the sub-selects.

Comment: You can't. There may be as many sub-queries as you like. Simple as that.

Comment: What do you exactly want to get from string above?

Comment: @Shafizadeh I want to create two strings. One with value: select start_dtm FROM schema.table 
where table_ID = (SELECT MAX(table_ID) 
FROM schema.table WHERE MAINT_APP = 'JOB01') and the other with: select end_dtm FROM schema.table
where table_ID = (SELECT MAX(table_ID) 
FROM schema.table WHERE MAINT_APP = 'JOB01')

Comment: Try this `where[\w*\s*]*\(\s*(select[\w*\s*\.*=*\(\)\']*)\s*and\s*\(\s*(select[\w*\s*\.*=*\(\)\']*)\s` . it will work only for your current query https://regex101.com/r/cO5oN1/1

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera could you write that pattern in JAVA code itself. That seems to be throwing escape errors for me.

Comment: @JoshKni8 check my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
String text = "where create_dtm between (select start_dtm FROM schema.table where table_ID = (SELECT MAX(table_ID) FROM schema.table WHERE MAINT_APP = 'JOB01'))"
                + "and (select end_dtm FROM schema.tablewhere table_ID = (SELECT MAX(table_ID) "
                + "FROM schema.table WHERE MAINT_APP = 'JOB01')) ";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "where[\\w*\\s*]*\\(\\s*(select[\\w*\\s*\\.*=*\\(\\)\\']*)\\s*and\\s*\\(\\s*(select[\\w*\\s*\\.*=*\\(\\)\\']*)\\s");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        if (m.matches()) {
            String group1 = m.group(1);
            String group2 = m.group(2);
            System.out.println(group1+"\n"+ group2);
        }
```

**Output**

> select start_dtm FROM schema.table where table_ID = (SELECT
>   MAX(table_ID) FROM schema.table WHERE MAINT_APP = 'JOB01')) select
>   end_dtm FROM schema.tablewhere table_ID = (SELECT MAX(table_ID) FROM
>   schema.table WHERE MAINT_APP = 'JOB01'))

**Note:** It will work only for your current query as mentioned in comments